# How to assert_called_once_with() for one specific argument or a sub set of arguments?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am using pytest and unittest modules. I want to assert that a `Mock` object that I am testing was accessed once and I want to assert that it was called with a specific value but only of ONE of many arguments. For example if the mocked method is:

```
def my_method(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(arg1)
```

and I call the mocked object with `mocked_method(arg1=3, arg2='smthng', arg3=80)` I wish to assert that : `mocked_method.assert_called_once_with(arg1=3)` and I dont care about the rest of the arguments. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found that we can achieve this in a simpler way than suggested in the comment below the original post by using `ANY`. So in my case that would be:

```
from unittest.mock import ANY

mocked_method.assert_called_once_with(arg1=3, arg2=ANY, arg3=ANY)
```